# Export products from Mysql Magento

Tags: parsing, magento, csv, export, product

I have some problems with Magento DB, i cannot match the attributes for my custom products export file.

I need help to get attributes, i have finished this script only with this header 
But attribute_set, visibility and size_cloth is returning number not name. maybe this can be resolved with a match function.

I need to get more attributes, ex: category_ids, i cannot get this...
color, size_shoes, size_etc.

Please check my script.

```
'store', '_website', 'attribute_set', 'type', 'sku', 'name', 'description', 'short_description', 'visibility', 'has_option', 'price', 'special_price', 'size_cloth', 'link', 'image'



<?php

    //Setup Connection information
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'user';
    $dbpass = 'pass';

    //Connect to the database
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die('Error connecting to mysql');

    //Point to specific DB
    $dbname = 'database_name';
    mysql_select_db($dbname);

    //Create the Query to get the products
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT P.attribute_set_id, P.type_id, P.sku, P.has_options, V.value AS Name, T1.value AS ProdDesc, T2.value AS ShortDesc,
    T5.value AS visibility, D.value AS Price, S.value AS Special_Price, SIZE_CLOTH.value AS size_cloth, CONCAT('http://www.website.com/', V1.value) AS Link, 
    CASE
        WHEN V2.Value IS NULL
            THEN NULL
        ELSE CONCAT('http://www.website.com/media/catalog/product', V2.value)
    END AS Image
    FROM  catalog_product_entity AS P INNER JOIN

    catalog_product_entity_varchar AS V  ON P.entity_id = V.entity_id  AND V.attribute_id  = 60  LEFT JOIN
    catalog_product_entity_varchar AS V1 ON P.entity_id = V1.entity_id AND V1.attribute_id = 87  LEFT JOIN
    catalog_product_entity_varchar AS V2 ON P.entity_id = V2.entity_id AND V2.attribute_id = 74  LEFT JOIN
    catalog_product_entity_text    AS T1 ON P.entity_id = T1.entity_id AND T1.attribute_id = 61  LEFT JOIN
    catalog_product_entity_text    AS T2 ON P.entity_id = T2.entity_id AND T2.attribute_id = 62  LEFT JOIN
    catalog_product_entity_int    AS T5 ON P.entity_id = T5.entity_id AND T5.attribute_id = 91 LEFT JOIN
    catalog_product_entity_decimal AS D  ON P.entity_id = D.entity_id  AND D.attribute_id  = 64 LEFT JOIN
    catalog_product_entity_int AS SIZE_CLOTH  ON P.entity_id = SIZE_CLOTH.entity_id  AND SIZE_CLOTH.attribute_id  = 122 LEFT JOIN
    catalog_product_entity_decimal AS S  ON P.entity_id = S.entity_id  AND S.attribute_id  = 65";

    //Run the query
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    //But after this i will prepare the csv file for export.
    $file = fopen('products_export.csv', 'w');
    // Custom header for csv file
    $header = array('store', '_website', 'attribute_set', 'type', 'sku', 'name', 'description', 'short_description', 'visibility', 'has_option', 'price', 'special_price', 'size_cloth', 'link', 'image');
    // this will arrange all data by comma 
    fputcsv($file, $header, ',', '"');    
    //Loop through and print each products info
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
        { 
        $item = array();
            $value1 = ("admin");
            $value2 = ("base");
            $value3 = ($row['attribute_set_id']);
            $value4 = ($row['type_id']);
            $value5 = ($row['sku']);
            $value6 = ($row['Name']);
            $value7 = ($row['ProdDesc']);
            $value8 = ($row['ShortDesc']);
            $value9 = ($row['visibility']);
            $value10 = ($row['has_options']);
            $value11 = ($row['Price']);
            $value111 = ($row['Special_Price']);
            $value112 = ($row['size_cloth']);
            $value12 = ($row['Link']);
            //$value13 = ($row['Image']);
            $item[] = $value1;
            $item[] = $value2;
            $item[] = $value3;
            $item[] = $value4;
            $item[] = $value5;
            $item[] = $value6;
            $item[] = $value7;
            $item[] = $value8;
            $item[] = $value9;
            $item[] = $value10;
            $item[] = $value11;
            $item[] = $value111;
            $item[] = $value112;
            $item[] = $value12;

            // put all data in csv file
            fputcsv($file, $item, ',', '"');    
        }
        {
            // close csv file and finish.
        fclose($file);
   }
?>
```

I think that the best solution will be the data.
Example:

```
if ( $value112 == need to array the list of numbers, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) {
    echo "S, M, L, XL";
} else {
    echo " ";
}
```

But i dont know how to insert this to my array items...

Comment: Why not just use a recognised product export mechanism ... Eg. DataFlow or a 3rd party extension like uRapidFlow

Comment: Did you found a workaround? I need this so much!.

Answer (score 2):

Interacting directly with Magento's DB wouldn't be my 1st choice. 
Alternatives that actually work:

1. Use Magento Import/Export module
2. Use Magento Dataflow Import/Export
3. Use Magento's product collection to generate the export file
   http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-8-varien-data-collections

Comment: 3 for the win. If you need custom reporting or exports, using Magento's product collection takes care of all the above fluff. There's no quicker way do drive yourself into the loony bin than attempting to work through all those nasty self-joins to get there. Alan Storm's website is a good place to begin understanding working with this stuff. http://alanstorm.com/category/magento